# How to change Angular Material mat-slide-toggle properties?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2, angular8

```
<mat-slide-toggle>Slide Me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

[image]

[image]

How to increase length of the toggle-thumb-icon,is it possible to customise the toggle-thumb-icon to the end of the bar?

Comment: it works that way, can you create a demo with stackblitz? what do you actually want

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aop7wy                                                                             Above is the working example for the same.Actually i want to slide the toggle to the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with the simple style

```
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    transform: translate3d(32px,0,0) !important;
}
```

[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txp1ws?file=src/styles.css)